# Game Quiz issues

Tags: python

my program keeps returning a score of 0 everytime I run it even with the corrcect answer. Also how would I go about subtractiong points for a wrong answer.

P.S, This is my first time coding anything.

```
score = 0
print('Math Quiz')


def check_answer(question, answer):
    global score
    if question == answer:
        print("Correct answer!")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print('Sorry, wrong answer.')


question_1 = input('What is 2 times 2?\n')
check_answer(question_1, 4)
question_2 = input('What is 1 minus 1?\n')
check_answer(question_2, 0)
question_3 = input('What is 4 divided by 2?\n')
check_answer(question_3, 2)
question_4 = input('What is 3 to the third power?\n')
check_answer(question_4, 9)
question_5 = input('What is 3 times 5?\n')
check_answer(question_5, 15)


print(score)
```

Comment: the tabs did not copy correctly, but everything is properly indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that `input()` returns a string which leads to an incompatible comparison of your data types. You could solve this by creating an integer with the value of your input like this: `question_1 = int(input('What is 2 times 2?\n'))`

the other problem could be solved by decreasing the score in your else block

Answer (score 0):

input('') returns a string and you are comparing it to a int.

```
check_anser(int(question_2),0)
```

or comparte to string version of the numbers

```
check_anser(question_2,"0")
```